# Cant scrolling during .notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: post, scroll, runnable, notifydatasetchanged

In following project [here is example](http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.com/2013/02/android-notifydatasetchanged.html)

I'm using with `.notifyDataSetChanged();` this method `.post(new Runnable(){` to scroll down after adding new item

```
 private void addItemsToList() {  
           int randomVal = MIN + (int) (Math.random() * ((MAX - MIN) + 1));  
           mItems.add(String.valueOf(randomVal));  
           mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

           mCompleteListView.post(new Runnable(){
              public void run() {
                  mCompleteListView.setSelection(mCompleteListView.getCount() - 1);
              }}); 
      }  


public class ReceiverThread extends Thread {
     String line;
     String name;

     ReceiverThread(String name, String line){
         this.line=line;
         this.name=name;

     }

     public void run() { 
     OpenStream.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    addItemsToList();}}}}
```

**BUT** when I want scroll up by using finger, new programmatically added item scrolls listview to down.

How I can set off `.post(new Runnable()` when I touch the screen and using finger to scroll? or what can I do to don't let listview scroll down when I touch the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I've added this code, and now when I touch listview there is no scrolling to down**

```
 mCompleteListView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() { 

    @Override 
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) { 
    flag = true; 
    Log.e(MainActivity.tag,"onTouch "+flag); 
    }else{ 
    flag = false; 
    Log.e(MainActivity.tag,"onTouch "+flag); 
    } 

    return false; 
    } 
    });
```